# View helper to split list in two column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a little problem.

I'm rendering a definition list in my haml view. Here is the code.

```
    .col
      - @product.data.each do |features_group_id, features_group|
        .data-group
          %h3= features_group["name"]
          %dl
            - features_group['features'].each do |id, hash|
              - if @product.product_category.show_feature_ids.include?(id)
                %span.data-wrap
                  %dt
                    = hash['name']
                  %dd
                    = hash['value']
```

I must split this list in two column.

I must take product.data.count/2 and show the two blocks in two column

```
    .col
      - @product.data_batch1.each do |features_group_id, features_group|
        .data-group
          %h3= features_group["name"]
          %dl
            - features_group['features'].each do |id, hash|
              - if @product.product_category.show_feature_ids.include?(id)
                %span.data-wrap
                  %dt
                    = hash['name']
                  %dd
                    = hash['value']
    .col
      - @product.data_batch2.each do |features_group_id, features_group|
        .data-group
          %h3= features_group["name"]
          %dl
            - features_group['features'].each do |id, hash|
              - if @product.product_category.show_feature_ids.include?(id)
                %span.data-wrap
                  %dt
                    = hash['name']
                  %dd
                    = hash['value']
```

Any easy solution to do this?

Comment: how the batch is split. is it first half and second half?

Comment: @emaillenin yes, if product.data.count is 18 two batch of 9, if 13 -> 7 + 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [in_groups_of](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of), given that `@product.data` is or acts as an `Array`.

From your code:

```
    - @product.data.in_groups_of(2, false).each do |group|
      .col
        - group.each do |features_group_id, features_group|
          .data-group
            %h3= features_group["name"]
            %dl
              - features_group['features'].each do |id, hash|
                - if @product.product_category.show_feature_ids.include?(id)
                  %span.data-wrap
                    %dt
                      = hash['name']
                    %dd
                      = hash['value']
```

There is even [a Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/28-in-groups-of) on this! :-)